# delete shared preferences on installing new version of application in development android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am developing Android application and I am using SharedPreferences for user credentials. My application is in development phase, so I like to delete shared preferences on installing new version of the application. Uninstalling previous version does not achive this. How can I achive this, because when I install new version of my application, the application read shared preferences like user was logged in   previously. This is normal application behavior, however I would like while development, to delete shared preferences file, but only on first application start, because I also like to test if user is logged in on other application execution.

Comment: you want to do this in your application code?

Comment: yes I would like to this in application code if there is another way you can suggest me

Comment: @vikifor: without code, you can do it manually by going in Settings app and clicking on `Clear data` button for your app.

Comment: @Mehul Joisar clear data button for my application is disabled

Comment: @vikifor stop your application, then it should be enabled.

Answer (score 2):

you can use versionCode in manifest. increment it when you make a new development. and then, check this to delete SharedPreference

```
try {
    PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("NAME", 0);
    if (pref.getInt("VERSION_CODE", 0) != pInfo.versionCode) {
        Editor edit = pref.edit();
        edit.clear();
        edit.putInt("VERSION_CODE", pInfo.versionCode);
        edit.commit();
    }
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}
```